# Google Maps api v3 get start and end coordinates of a street

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I want to highlight a specific street by name. I can do this with the start and end coordinates of a street. I don't want to pass in coordinates but the street name. Google Maps will return the street coordinates but I need both start and end coordinates.

```
request = {
   origin: "streetname",
   destination: "streetname",
   travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
};
```

In this example it will return the same coordinates for origin and destination.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Maps API v3 doesn't do that.  You need to find a different data source or manually determine the coordinates.